# Do I need access to the server?

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento and was wondering a very basic thing, I saw that in order to change some things on the web I have directories such as `app/design/frontend/.....` so my question is, is there a way to access this files from magento admin panel or I necessarily need to check them from the server?

Comment: you question is confusing.Actually what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to edit the css of a plugin but it said the files are inside this folder app/design/frontend/base/default/template/onestepcheckout i want to know if i can access this folder from within the admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access this folder in admin panel.You need to go to the mentioned file location and change there whatever you want.

If your application is on remote server you need ftp access.

```
 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/onestepcheckout
```

you can also copy the file to your theme and make changes there.

```
app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/onestepcheckout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only edit CMS content from the admin panel.

Modifying templates/css requires access to the file system (ftp/ssh).

Answer (score 0):

i don't this there's any why that help you to edit magento files without login to FTP / SFTP. so i think try to get FTP / SFTP details